# How to develop android mobile app with Exchange active-sync protocol

Tags: android, exchange-server, activesync

I am trying to develop an android app to access exchange 2016/2019 email through active sync protocol

I tried to look at 
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-ashttp/4cbf28dc-2876-41c6-9d87-ba9db86cd40d

2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Any email mobile developer can tip me some direction through this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a sample implementation (in C#) over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-interoperability-guidance/jj572420(v%3dexchg.140)

It compiles almost out-of-the-box and it contains everything you need to build a working client - the WBXML decoder/encoder, a sample implementation for most sync commands, etc.